# Screen Resolution Concern in Google Analytics Mobile App

Tags: google, google-analytics, analytics, resolution

I stumbled upon my Google Analytics screen resolution report and saw this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XD0X9.jpg]

Are they the same screen resolution since they do have separate sessions in Google Analytics? What's the reason behind this? :( How can we resolve this for reporting purposes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, it's not the same resolution.

One number represents horizontal size, other number represents vertical size.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this man! Regarding the sessions, even if  the session timer is running, as long as the GA first recorded that the device is used horizontally which 1920x1090, when shifted to vertical, it will not be counted for 1090x1920?